# Recorder not recording properly

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I've been trying to record a macro in Excel 2016 on my new computer.

After I finish recording, I try it out and get a syntax error.

I looked at the code, and see:

```vb
    Cells.ErrorString
    With .
        . = xlSolid
        . = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlThemeColorDark1
        .Symbol = 0
        . = 0
    End With
    With
        . = xlGeneral
        . = xlCenter
        . = FALSE
        . = 0
        . = FALSE
        . = 0
        . = FALSE
        . = xlContext
        . = FALSE
    End With
    .SourceName = 11.44
    .SortItems = 21.6
End Sub
```

It looks like there should be something before or after the (.) on each line.

Comment: There should be an object after the "With" keyword, that is what will be used inside the With - End With scope. The idea of "With" is to shorten the code by declaring the object once.

Comment: I've seen this before, also on a recent purchased computer.  Close everything, reboot, let Office finish installing, then try again. You can expedite the process by going to `Start` > `Add/Remove Programs`, **right-click** Microsoft Office in the list of programs, and choose "`Repair`".  Once it's fully complete, reboot again.

Comment: Thank you, st_stefanov and ashleedawg! The repair worked! Thank you for saving me from so much stress :)

Comment: @ashleedawg if you have a chance, post that as an answer - looks like something that can be helpful to others =)